# How to upload empty folder on s3 using rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I create object for empty folder but I am unable to put it on S3. 
I am using the gem 'aws-sdk', '< 2.0'

I tried with the 'put' method, and I also tried with 'put_object', but I can't get it to work. Can anyone help me?

The code I am using with put_object is:

```
 key = 'folder'+'/'+subfolder+'/'    
    folder_key = S3_BUCKET.objects[key]
    folder_key.put_object
```

And the error I receive is:

```
error : undefined method `put_object' for <AWS::S3::S3Object:bucketname/folder/subfolder/>:AWS::S3::S3Object
```

When using the 'put' method:

```
    folder_key.put()
```

The error I receive is:

```
error : undefined method `put' for <AWS::S3::S3Object:bucketname/folder/subfolder/>:AWS::S3::S3Object
```

Where S3_BUCKET defines credentials for S3.

Here folder key create object for folder but how to store it on s3

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you a little walkthrough of creating objects in S3, as I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, so perhaps a general overview will help.

The `put_object` and `put` methods are defined on the S3::Client class, not the object bucket. That is why you are receiving the error you are - they are not methods on the S3Object class.

With that in mind, you first need to instantiate an S3 Client:

```
profile_name = 'Rinkal'
region = 'us-east-1'
s3 = Aws::S3::Client.new(profile: profile_name, region: region)
```

You can now interact with S3 via the client we just created. This is, of course, assuming you've configured your S3 authentication correctly - more info on that [here.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/developer-guide/setup-config.html)

Assuming you have your bucket name (it seems like in your code this is folder_key), you can then create an object within that bucket:

```
s3.put_object(bucket: folder_key, key: "file", body: "Rinkal's s3 object")
```

If you wish to create a bucket, and not an object, you can do that with the following code:

`s3.create_bucket(bucket: 'my-bucket')`

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such concept as a "folder" in S3. What I think you are referring to is the key prefix, which looks like a folder path before the filename, but is not.

S3 is simply a key value store. The **key is a unique string**, and the **value is a blob**.

To qualify the key, people often use a path like key, and the S3 console supports this format to drill down in a folder style structure, making it easier to manually find objects. This is just a text filter on the key, like a startsWith() filter.

If you don't have an object with a particular key prefix, then the so called path does not exist.

It is not 100% clear what you are trying to achieve, but in short:

> You do not need to create a folder before uploading a file with a new prefix. Simply upload the object with the desired key.

See Stuart's answer for how to achieve that in rails.